# Size of Collada Object

Tags: javascript, three.js, size, collada

Fist time I'm working with javascript, WebGL and Three.js. 
I added dae 3D model to my scene and now I have to get it's size to generate objects inside of it. But when I added dae object, it displayed rotated on the scene. As I read somewhere and also tested, I can't just rotate my object because bounding box will not rotate with it. What should I do to get the size of the object?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Collada Size.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script>

    window.onload = function () {

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(800, 600);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                55,             // Field of view
                800 / 600,      // Aspect ratio
                0.1,            // Near plane
                1000           // Far plane
        );
        camera.position.set(-15, 1000, 10);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        loader.load('models/MyFile.dae', function (collada) {
            var dae = collada.scene;
            var skin = collada.skins[0];
            dae.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            //dae.rotation.y = 45;
            render();
            dae.scale.set(120, 150, 120);
            scene.add(dae);

            sizeofDesk(dae);
        });

        function sizeofDesk(dae) {

            var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(dae, 0xff0000);
            helper.update();
            // If you want a visible bounding box
            scene.add(helper);
            // If you just want the numbers
            var min = helper.box.min;
            var max = helper.box.max;

            console.log(min);
            console.log(max);
        }

        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        dirLight.position.set(100, 100, 50);
        scene.add(dirLight);

        renderer.setClearColor(0xffe5e5, 1);

        render();

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: will your object be deforming? Otherwise you can get the bounding box at init time and rotate it as you rotate the object.

Answer (score 0):

You using `dae.scale.set(120, 150, 120);` Are you sure you want to scale object 150 times? Default scale is `dae.scale.set(1,1,1)`.

You can setup `obj = new THREE.Object3D();scene.add(obj);` and your model put to the object `obj.add(dae);` Then you can manipulate with object (pre-scale object, rotate and translate.)...